# picturebox selected property?

Tags: picturebox, selected

I'm wondering if there's a property in the picturebox control that will tell when it is selected?

I have a set of pictureboxes shown in a form, then the user can click on any, when that happens, I use this code to change some visuals to indicate the user he selected it.

```
private void clickpicbox(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

        imagenseleccionada = ((System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox)sender).Tag.ToString();
        int i = Int32.Parse(imagenseleccionada);

     if (picbox[i].BorderStyle == BorderStyle.Fixed3D)
        {
            picbox[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

        }
        else
        {
            picbox[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;

        }
}
```

Now, this is only visual stuff to the user. What I'd like to do is set a property for a picturebox[i] that will tell is selected so I can later on perform some actions for ONLY those that were selected..

how can I perform that?

Answer (score 0):

it's easier to use `e.Location` which contains `Point` of mouse click.

Comment: So that Mouse point is a point in the screen or a point in the image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134447/mouse-click-location-on-a-picturebox-not-detected-within-label  - see the answer. you can locate correct picturebox with it